# RESTful APIの独自ヘッダー情報について

Tags: http, rest

質問：
RESTful APIを作成する際に、httpヘッダーに独自ヘッダーを設定することがあると思いますが、どういった目的で設定をしているのでしょうか。

以下の記事ではCSRF対策として独自ヘッダーを導入することを検証しています。

[独自ヘッダをチェックするだけのステートレスなCSRF対策は有効なのか？](http://blog.a-way-out.net/blog/2015/03/23/stateless-csrf-protection/)

記事にあるように「CSRF対策」といった目的があると思っているのですが、理解ができておりません。